# Mysql 5.6.12 bug : error 1356 when using order by alias in a view definition

Tags: mysql

I have a very simple Query, which works fine:

```
SELECT *
FROM images i
INNER JOIN v_images_stats s
ON i.id = s.id
```

By `SELECT *` I end up creating duplicate column names so I edited the query to be more specific
and ignore the duplicate column names but MySQL throws a #1356 error:

```
SELECT i.is as id, s.id as imageid
FROM images i
INNER JOIN v_images_stats s
ON i.id = s.id
```

> #1356 - View 'events.v_image_stats' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them

The v_image_stats view and the underlying views and tables it is based have the correct privileges, I'm completely flummoxed.

I'm using MySQL 5.6 and phpmyadmin to create and manage the views, I am also accessing the DB via PHP PDO within the Phalcon framework but I'm pretty sure this a MySQL issue rather than anything else.

Any help gratefully received.

I originally posted the full output of SHOW CREATE VIEW but it was too verbose, here is the simplest example I can create to recreate the problem:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`events`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `v_image_stats` AS
(
    select it.*, 1 AS `my_alias`
    from `v_image_totals` `it`
    order by `my_alias` asc)
)
```

It also fails if I use a table instead of a view in the FROM clause.

Comment: post the `SHOW CREATE VIEW` output

Comment: The problem seems to be caused by ordering a view by a column alias. I can't find a MySQL bug or known limitation related to this, can anyone recreate this?

Comment: if you remove the `order by` it works? or if you order it by column name not alias ?

Comment: Both. If I remove the ORDER BY it works also if I keep the ORDER BY but use a real column name instead of an alias it works.

Comment: I can workaround this by removing the ORDER BY clause add adding it to the query in the PHP code but it seems like it should work.

Comment: why don't you use order by column name instead? to avoid sorting in php

Comment: because in my VIEW the alias I want to ORDER BY is an expression based on more than one underlying column e.g. (a.my_apples/b.total_apples) AS avg_apples

Comment: then try `ORDER BY  (a.my_apples/b.total_apples)`

Comment: thanks, that does work and means I don't have to do the ORDER BY in my PHP code which in someways is an improvement but introduces a bit of a maintenance headache in the SQL VIEW because I'm having to duplicate a complex expression, which won't be obvious to someone else looking at the query. Do you agree that it's odd that this works in a query but not in a view?

Comment: yes, i think its a mysql bug and i'm glad we reached a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug affecting MySQL 5.6.10 and above (I have not tested against MySQL 5.7).
I have raised a bug with MySQL so this can be tracked and hopefully fixed:
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69678

See the comments for an effective workaround.